# Looping to display on LEDs HCS12 microcontroller

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 68hc12

hello i am trying to do a loop in assembly language to make the LEDs light up on a HCS12 microcontroller (Dragon12p). the value is displayed on the LEDs as its binary equivalent (e.g. $01 would light up first LED, $99 would like up like 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1, $23 like 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1).

```
             org     $2000
STACK        equ     $2000
DELAY_VALUE  equ     64
ENDCOUNT     equ     $99
Start        lds     #STACK
             jsr     Config_SWs_and_LEDs 

Startover    ldaa    $00       ; load accumulator a with $00
Loop         staa    PORTB     ; send data to PORTB to display LED
             jsr     Delay_ms  ; delay by 64 ms
             inca              ; increment accumulator a by one value
             cmpa    #ENDCOUNT ; compare accumulator a to ENDCOUNT ($99)
             bgt     Loop      ; branch if accumulator a is less than $99
             bra     Startover ; start over at $00 if accumulator a reaches $99

             end
```

Hwoever, my loop does not work, inca only increments a by 1 once, so when i test this code only the first LED lights up. cant figure this out.

Comment: What does `Delay_ms` do?  Will it overwrite the accumulator? Also shouldn't your conditional jump be `BLO`? (you want to loop as long as the accumulator is < $99)

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Believe Michael. The bgt Loop is the wrong way.
Also it may not be what you were looking for.
Now it displays (if the bgt Loop is corrected), in binary, the numbers from 0 to 99 and
pauses 64 ms for each number. That is 0.06 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing what professors find on-line.

jsr Delay_ms calls a library function that delays the HCS12 uController by a multiple of the value in Accumulator A. And yes, A is indeed destroyed in Delay_ms.

Unsigned branches should have been used unless a blt is meant to check for -1, which is not the case here.